# jQuery DataTables "No data available in table" JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I'm struggling with ""No data available in table" in DataTables. My problem is that I have a JSON array sent by server-side and I got the response but the DataTable can't read it so I don't know how to solve this issue.

So here is my code for the .

```
var table = $('#opportunities').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": 'api/opportunities/article/' + id,
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" }, 
        { "data": "status" }, 
        { "data": "eval.4" }, 
        { "data": "eval.3" }, 
        { "data": "articleName" }
    ]
});
```

here is my json response from the server

```
{
    "85": {
        "id": 85,
        "idArticle": 109,
        "articleName": "pozjdpoo",
        "status": "baseline",
        "name": "blabla for test",
        "responsable": "blabla for test",
        "description": "",
        "credibilite": 0.0,
        "commentaires": "",
        "link": "",
        "PJ": null,
        "affectedArticle": null,
        "eval": {
            "id": 52,
            "opp": 85,
            "coeff": null,
            "score": null
        }
    },
    "56": {
        "id": 56,
        "idArticle": 109,
        "articleName": "pozjdpoo",
        "status": "Initial",
        "name": "report",
        "responsable": "report",
        "description": null,
        "credibilite": 0.0,
        "commentaires": null,
        "link": null,
        "PJ": null,
        "affectedArticle": null,
        "eval": null
    }
}
```

and then on my page, in my table row I got no data available message

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbFDJ.png

Comment: Is this correct json response as mentioned in the datatable documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Your json response format should be like below:

```
{"recordsTotal":"##number of total results",
 "recordsFiltered":"##number of filtered results(if any filter like search is applied)",
 "data":[
          ["##name1","##status1","##eval.41","##eval.31","##articleName1"],
          ["##name2","##status2","##eval.42","##eval.32","##articleName2"],
        ]
}
```

Where ##name1, ##status1 are the corresponding values.